# Ruby on Rails and Postgresql - Server is running, but I'm obtaining a could not connect to server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**QUESTION: PostgreSQL server is running, but when I run rake db:migrate, I obtain a ConnectionBad: could not connect to server error. What can I do to fix this error?**

**Update - Database.yml file**

I've removed some points in the file for anonymity.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: db_development
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password: 

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: db_test
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: db_production
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password:
```

I've looked through the API and tried to implement the answers, but nothing is working on my end.

When I run `pg_lsclusters`, I'm told:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main 
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

So it's online, I usually start the server as `sudo service postgresql start`.

However, when I try and run `rake db:migrate`, I get the error:

`PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

I haven't encountered this error before, is it possible I have uninstalled postgresql wrongly?

I did it as:
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev`
`gem install pg`

And in the Ruby on Rails app:

`bundle install`
`bundle update`

Everything installed perfectly, so I just don't know what I have done wrong, given I've done those steps before on another computer and it works fine for it.

Comment: Please enclose the contents of your database.yml file

Comment: Hi hd1, I've just added the file in now, with some points removed for anonymity.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with the command line?

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `port: 5433` to your database.yml.

The default PostgreSQL port is 5432, but your `pg_lsclusters` command says the server is running on 5433. This is why Rails can’t find a server running on localhost:5432.